# Countability of $\mathbb{N}^3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

In Sipser's book (2nd edition), Exercise 4.7 asks to show that $T = \{(i,j,k) | i,j,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable.

Here is what I did.

Let $A = (i,j,k)$.

Let $B = (i+1,j+1,k+1)$.

$A$ and $B$ are sets. $i,j,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I create a function $f(i,j,k) = (i+1, j+1, k+1)$. $T$ is countable because for every element in the set $A$, $f$ maps it to a different element in $B$. Also $f$ hits every element in $B$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Not sure I got you right, but I think that in your example $A=B$, then you have just shown that $A$ maps to itself. Try to map $A$ to a set that you know to be countable, like $\mathbb{N}$, i.e., set $B=\mathbb{N}$ and now find a bijection from $A=T$ to $B=\mathbb{N}$

Comment: This looks like a pure math question, and thus off-topic here.  (Math questions can potentially be on-topic here if there is a reason why they need to be answered from a computer science perspective and if that reason is explained in the question, but I don't see that here.)  I'll migrate to Math.SE, where math questions are on-topic.

Comment: The way you wrote it A and B are single elements.  If you wrote them as sets then A = B = T and you've mapped T to T.  You need to map N to T and show it is 1 -1

Answer (score 4):

The proposed proof is for the fact that $|A|=|B|$.  However it does not tell us that either set is countable.

One function that would work is $$f(i,j,k)=2^i3^j5^k$$
This is a one-to-one function from $T$ to $\mathbb{N}$.  Hence we have $|T|\le|\mathbb{N}|$, which proves that $T$ is either countable or finite.  But $T$ is obviously infinite, hence $T$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

To show T is coutable you need to show there is a 1-1 mapping from $\mathbb N^3$ to $\mathbb N$.

So you need to find a way to map a $(i,j,k) \rightarrow n$ and that if $f(i,j,k) =n$,  $(i,j,k)$ is the *only* triplet that maps to $n$.

The proof you all refer to suggests $f(i,j,k) = 2^i3^j5^k$.  This clearly maps $\mathbb N^3$ to $\mathbb N$.  But if $f(i,j,k) = 2^i3^j5^k=n$ is (i,j,k) the *only* triple that maps into n?

The prime factorization theorem states that there is only one way to prime factorize n.  If n only has 2,3 and 5 as prime factors then $2^i3^j5^k$ is the only way to factorize n.  So $(i,j,k)$ is the only triplet that maps to that particular $n$.

So each different triplet maps into a unique and different natural number.  So there is a one to one mapping from $\mathbb N^3$ to a subset of $\mathbb N$. So $\mathbb N^3$ is countable.